# How to calculate this limit？

Tags: webmathematica

Here is my question:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^2[(1+\frac{1}{1+n})^{n+1}-(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}]=?$

Any hints will be fine. Thank you!

Comment: [Documentation >> Limit](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Limit.html)

Answer (score 3):

As simple as using `Limit`:

```
Clear[n];
Limit[n^2 ((1 + 1/(1 + n))^(n + 1) - (1 + 1/n)^n), n -> ∞]
(*E/2*)
```